# What interstellar data rates are feasible?

Tags: interstellar-travel, radio-communication, optical-communication

Preamble: Mankind has colonized the galaxy with self replicating machines which build transceivers when they arrive at a new star system which transmit and receive uploaded human minds and AI between stars. We don't know the data size of those minds and therefore can't calculate how long it takes to transmit them, but I still want to know what data rates are feasible with current science/technology.

There might be 100,000 transmitters in 100 to 200 AU orbits around the star. How far should they be apart so receivers get low cross talk from adjacent transmitters. I guess transmission is via laser. Is radio worth it?

100 m diameter optical telescopes seem feasible: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_large_telescope .

How many channels are feasible? One laser per nanometer would give us 400 channels in the 400-800 nm range. I guess we can inject different wavelength lasers into one dish with a prism just like white light can be split with a prism. Off axis beams could target several receivers and multiply the number of channels. How do we modulate the lasers? Pulse lasers?

I guess interstellar distances range from <1 ly in star clusters and 100 ly in sparsely populated regions.

Assume a well organized system, so orbits of receivers will be well known/maintained to allow transmitters to use narrow beams.

Main question: What's the data rate (bit/s) per transmitter depending on range (1-100 ly), transmitter spacing (mas/milliarcseconds), transmit power and/or mirror size/quality?

Comment: If you place  transmitters in 100 to 200 AU orbits around the star, you don't achieve equal distant spacing for a longer time. Orbits periods depend on orbit radius. You need a huge number of transmitters for each single orbit.

Comment: @Uwe I thought of 101 circular orbits with 100..200 AU radius in one plane, filled with transmitters 1 AU apart. Distances of transmitters in adjacent obits would vary from 1-1.12 AU if I calculated correctly. That would work well, if the plane was perpendicular to the line to the star we want to communicate with. But there are other stars and stars drift chaotically, so some 3D transmitter population might be more generally useful even if we couldn't use them all at the same time.

Comment: This question is far too speculative for this site. It might get better traction at the [WorldBuildding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange.

Comment: Bandwidth works *roughly* the same way for optical fiber as it does in free-space optical, so you can start with that as a model. *Power* on the other hand is totally different. Fiber (guided) is exponential, free space is mostly inverse square. Fiber has strict limits due to nonlinear processes in the fiber, free space doesn't (except for absurdly large intensities, but here the beams will be large diameters so less of a problem). I'd say ask a narrower, for focused question about a very limited case rather than "how will they do it in the future" and this might be answerable.

Comment: In other words, perhaps just ask your "Main question: What's the data rate (bit/s) per transmitter depending on range (1-100 ly), transmitter spacing (mas/milliarcseconds), transmit power and/or mirror size/quality?" without all the future civilization stuff that might require speculation. *Thanks!*